# Interfacing Access Databases to Update Excel Spreadsheets

Tags: excel, ms-access, interface

Our department mantains several monthly Excel spreadsheets, with many of these spreadsheets including charts and graphs. Each month, data is collected for these spreadsheets using reports written in different departmental Access databases.

Obviously, maintaining/updating these spreadsheets is a lot of work and is open for human error. What I would like to create, is an Access database that makes this process much easier by updating these spreadsheets itself. Users would open this database, choose a spreadsheet, and the database woud pull data from the other departmental databases to generate the spreadsheet for the user.

The problem I am having is trying to decide how to interface this spreadsheet updating database with the other departmental databases. While they are databases within our department, I would like to interface them in a way that puts no new work upon them. In other words, I don't want to have to create or modify any queries, reports, tables, etc. in these databases. I'm also a little hesitant to link any tables as I don't want to run the risk of modifing any data. I simply want my database to ask the other databases for thier data, then use that data to update the spreadhseets. Keep in mind all of these databases are in Access, and all of the spreadsheets are in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want links to the tables in the other Access databases, you can use queries which include the full path to the source databases.

```sql
SELECT am.*
FROM AssetMovements AS am
    IN 'C:\share\Access\Assets.mdb';
```

Refine the query as needed, and save it as a named query.  Then you can use that query name as the *TableName* option for [DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb214134%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

```vb
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet TransferType:=acExport, _
    SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
    TableName:="qryAssets", _
    FileName:="C:\share\Access\Assets_20131217.xls", _
    HasFieldNames:=True
```